# Find elements in group by result use SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I have a table contain event log, schema:

```
userid, event, timestamp
```

I want group by userid and find that user have specific event

ex.

```
userid, events
A, "open, click, remove, restart"
```

so I want make group by result as a string / array

is there any way can do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

as an example - assuming you want to get list of all `ordered` events of users who have `remove` event:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT userid,
  STRING_AGG(event ORDER BY ts) AS events
FROM `project.dataset.yourtable`
GROUP BY userid
HAVING REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(events), r'\bremove\b')
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 'A' userid, 'open' event, 1 ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'click', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'remove', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'restart', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'open', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'click', 2   
)
SELECT userid,
  STRING_AGG(event ORDER BY ts) AS events
FROM `project.dataset.yourtable`
GROUP BY userid
HAVING REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(events), r'\bremove\b')
```

with result as below (user B is not presented because no remove even present for this user)

```
userid  events   
A       open,click,remove,restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the `group_concat` function in `BigQuery`.

```
select userid, group_concat(event, ', ') as events
from EventLog
group by userid;
```

You also briefly mention that you would like to find users that have specific events, you can add that in as part of the `where` clause, but as you did not give any example of how you are looking to narrow it down, I have omitted that portion. If you can give a more specific case example of what you are looking for, I can update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The functions are called either STRING_AGG or ARRAY_AGG when using standard SQL in BigQuery.